# Why does every /admin/... display the same content?

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

Here are some of the code, the issue is that it only displays the content from the first  tag, so admin/defectReports or viewAdmins will only display information from admin/viewCleaners. How do I make it so that different URLs will display different content?

index.js

```
const DefectReports = lazy(() => import('./components/dashboard/DefectReports'));
const ViewCleaners = lazy(() => import('./components/dashboard/ViewCleaners')); 
const ViewAdmins = lazy(() => import('./components/dashboard/ViewAdmins')); 
...
<Route exact path={localPath.viewCleaners} component={ViewCleaners} /> 
<Route exact path={localPath.defectReports} component={DefectReports} />
<Route exact path={localPath.viewAdmins} component={ViewAdmins} />
```

config.js

```
export const localPath = {
defectReportsPage: '/admin/defectReports', //admin
viewCleanersPage: '/admin/viewCleaners', //admin
viewAdminsPage: '/admin/viewAdmins'
}
```

ViewCleaners.js
I tried to simplify the code to make it easier to understand, please forgive any syntax mistakes

```
export class viewCleaners extends Component {

    state = {
        person: [],
        columns: [{
            dataField: 'Name',
            text: 'Name',
            sort: true
        }, {
            dataField: 'Rating',
            text: 'Rating',
            sort: true
        }]
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            person: [{ 
                Name: 'Becky Ann',
                Rating: 4.99
                }]
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container" >
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={2} id="sidebar-wrapper">
                        <SideBar />
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <div style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
                            <ToolkitProvider
                                keyField="Name"
                                data={this.state.person}
                                columns={this.state.columns}
                                search>
                                {
                                    props => (
                                        <div>
                                            <SearchBar {...props.searchProps} />
                                            <hr />
                                            <BootstrapTable
                                                striped
                                                hover
                                                pagination={paginationFactory()}
                                                {...props.baseProps}
                                            />
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                }
                            </ToolkitProvider>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default viewCleaners
```

Comment: Your config.js has localPath as `defectReportsPage`,`viewCleanersPage`,`viewAdminsPage` whereas index.js has `localPath.viewCleaners`,`localPath.defectReports`,`localPath.viewAdmins`. Is this a typo or error?

Comment: That's the error! thank you :)

Comment: If my above comment helped you in fixing your issue then please accept my answer posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your paths from :

`<Route exact path={localPath.viewCleaners} component={ViewCleaners} />`

`<Route exact path={localPath.defectReports} component={DefectReports} />`

`<Route exact path={localPath.viewAdmins} component={ViewAdmins} />`

to:

`<Route exact path={localPath.viewCleanersPage} component={ViewCleaners} />`

`<Route exact path={localPath.defectReportsPage} component={DefectReports} />`

`<Route exact path={localPath.viewAdminsPage } component={ViewAdmins} />`